# How to dedicate the installed programs with web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

One of my tasks is to create a web application which has icons for the
installed programs on the client PC as Adobe reader. I tried to use
this Javascript but it didn't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getActiveXObject(name) {
         try {
                return new ActiveXObject(name);
             }
             catch (err) {
                return undefined;
             }
      };
</script>
<div class="program-icon" id="Sap" runat="server"  >
    <a href="#" onclick="return getActiveXObject(SAP Logon);" runat="server">
        <img src="res/images/sap-icon.png" width="30" height="31" /><span>الساب</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the name be in apostrophes? I.e. `onclick="return getActiveXObject('SAP Logon');" ` ?

Comment: @TomasPastircak: Yes, but that's the least of his problems.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, web pages cannot detect or invoke client applications on the user's PC (this would be a grave security risk).

As your code snippet alludes, if a program exposes functionality as an ActiveX control, it *may* be possible to use this to detect or launch a program, but this would work only in IE, only in Desktop Mode, only when the ActiveX control is marked Safe-for-Scripting, and so forth.

Step back a bit: Why aren't you building a client application for this task?